# How to prove that: $f(A\cap B) \subseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$, and some few others

Tags: functions

With $f:X \rightarrow Y; A, B \subseteq X; C, D \subseteq Y$, I'm given these identities:
1. $f(A\cap B) \subseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$
2. $f(A\setminus B) \subseteq f(A) \setminus f(B)$
3. $f^{-1}(C\cap D) \subseteq f^{-1}(C) \cap f^{-1}(D)$
4. $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$
5.$f^{-1}(f^{-1}(C)) = C \cap f(X) \subseteq C$

Here's what I need to do:
a)Find examples of functions and non-empty sets A, B for which 1. and/or 2. aren't equal (i.e. they are $\subset$, but not $=$)
I believe this is the case for any non-injective function for which $a \neq b$ but $f(a) = f(b)$ , like $f(x) = |x|$, with $a = 1$ and $b=-1$. I'd like to hear some more examples of functions like this.
b)Here I need to find the same thing like a) but for identities 4 and 5, however I'm not sure what even to look for.
c) Prove 1 or 2 and 3 or 4. 
Here's my not so successful attempt at proving 1:
$f(A \cap B) = \{y \in Y : y = f(x) \wedge x \in A \cap B\} = \{y \in Y : y = f(x) \wedge (x \in A \wedge x \in B)\} = \{y \in Y : (y = f(x) \wedge x \in A) \wedge (y = f(x) \wedge x \in B)\} = \{y \in Y : y = f(x) \wedge x \in A\} \cap \{y \in Y : y = f(x) \wedge x \in B\} = f(A) \cap f(B)$

And I made an analogous "proof" for 2, however, obviously it's not right as I get that $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ instead of $\subseteq$. And for the second part of c) (i.e. 3 and 4), I'm not even sure how to start.

Any help at solving a) b) and c) is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1):** $A\cap B\subseteq A\Rightarrow f\left(A\cap B\right)\subseteq f\left(A\right)$
and $A\cap B\subseteq B\Rightarrow f\left(A\cap B\right)\subseteq f\left(B\right)$
. Consequence: $$f\left(A\cap B\right)\subseteq f\left(A\right)\cap f\left(B\right)$$

**2) is not true:** let $f$ be a constant function and let
$A\backslash B\neq\emptyset\wedge B\neq\emptyset$. Then $f\left(A\backslash B\right)\neq\emptyset$
and $f\left(A\right)\backslash f\left(B\right)=\emptyset$

**3):** $$x\in f^{-1}\left(C\cap D\right)\iff f\left(x\right)\in C\cap D\iff$$$$ f\left(x\right)\in C\wedge f\left(x\right)\in D\iff x\in f^{-1}\left(C\right)\cap f^{-1}\left(D\right)$$

**4):** $$x\in A\Rightarrow f\left(x\right)\in f\left(A\right)$$
combined with: $$f\left(x\right)\in f\left(A\right)\iff x\in f^{-1}\left(f\left(A\right)\right)$$

**Adjusted 5):** To be proved is probably $f\left(f^{-1}\left(C\right)\right)=C\cap f\left(X\right)$

(the notation $f^{-1}\left(f^{-1}\left(C\right)\right)$ makes no
sense).

$$y\in f\left(f^{-1}\left(C\right)\right)\iff y=f\left(x\right)\text{ for some }x\in f^{-1}\left(C\right)\iff y\in C\cap f\left(X\right)$$

Comment: thanks a lot! Do you know any examples of a set and a function for which in 4) we cannot use "="?
And when it comes to $f^{−1}(f^{−1}(C))=C∩f(X) ⊆ C$
why do you say it makes no sense? Perhaps it's just untrue, which is possible, because the assingment does say "prove 3 _or_ 5".

Comment: To your last question: $f^{-1}(C)$ is a subset of $X$ (not of $Y$). Only subsets of $Y$ have preimages under $f$ so there is no preimage of $f^{-1}(C)$, i.e. $f^{-1}(f^{-1}(C))$ makes no sense.

Comment: On your first question: If $f$ is a constant function and $\emptyset\neq A$ then $f^{-1}(f(A)=X$. Any set $A$ with $\emptyset\neq A\neq X$ will do then

Comment: How come? Say that we have A = {1, 2}, f(x) = 5. In that case f⁻¹(f{A}) = R, then clearly A is a subset of R.

Comment: Indeed, a subset. But normally a *proper* subset. So $\subseteq$ and also $\subset$ are okay here but $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$ is *not* okay and you asked for "a function wich in 4) we cannot use "$=$"". Btw, why do you speaking of $R$ here? The domain of $f$ in your question is $X$, not $R$.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake, for some reason I forgot that the question was about "=" and not a subset in general. Big thanks, you helped me a lot.

Comment: drhab, I have another question concerning 5. If f⁻¹ is Y' -> X, then why is not f⁻¹(f⁻¹)) X' -> Y'? (X' and Y' are subsets of X and Y)

Comment: I believe f^-1 f^-1 here is meant to denote "inverse function of an inverse function".
Or in other words, I need an example of a function for which the image of its inverse function of its inverse function is not completely equal to the original function.

Comment: On your last comment: believe it or not, but that is definitely not true. You can only speak of an inverse function $f^{-1}$ if the original function $f$ is bijective, and nothing is said about that here. There are more things to mention that deny your belief.

Comment: On your former comment. Here $f^{-1}(D)$ is **not** the notation of the **image** of $D$ under function $f^{-1}$ but it is the notation of the **preimage** of $D$ under function $f$. You are confusing these concepts here. In this context you better forget about any function $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Generally speaking, is there a possibility that this was just an example of bad notation and was meant to be "inverse function of an inverse function" (let's just call it g for the sake of brevity)?
In that case, is there an example of a function for which that function g ('s image) wouldn't be the same as f(X)?
Once again, big thanks for your patience and helpfulness. I realize I might have asked a bad question now, but this came in my homework and I don't feel like losing points.

Comment: No on your question. Btw, if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ then (if an inverse
exists, i.e. if $f$ is bijective) $f^{-1}:Y\rightarrow X$ so that
the function $f^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$ can only exist if $Y=X$. Next
to that a correct notation for 'inverse of inverse' would not be $f^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$
but $\left(f^{-1}\right)^{-1}$. This with $\left(f^{-1}\right)^{-1}=f$.
The 'inverse of inverse of $f$ is $f$ itself. I am convinced that
the notation $f^{-1}\left(f^{-1}\left(C\right)\right)$ in 5) was wrong and was meant to be $f\left(f^{-1}\left(C\right)\right)$,
so that it indeed equals $C\cap f\left(X\right)$.

Comment: I asked the professor about this, and it turns out that indeed it was a mistake and was fixed to $f(f^{-1}(C))$. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

for a), consider the function $f(x) = x^2 $ and put $A = [-1,0) $ and $B = (0,1] $, then

$$ A \cap B = \varnothing \implies f( A \cap B ) = \varnothing $$

but, $f(A) = f(B) = (0,1] $, hence

$$ f(A) \cap f(B) = (0,1] $$

Answer (score 0):

To show $X\subseteq Y$, it is often easiest to show that $x\in X\implies x\in Y$. For example, if $x\in f(A\cap B)$, then $x=f(y)$ for some $y\in A\cap B$. Then $y \in A$, so $x\in f(A)$, and similarly $x\in f(B)$. Hence, $x\in f(A)\cap f(B)$.